# How to load html pages one after the other with js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose i have 4 html pages say a.html,b.html,c.html and d.html.

Initially when i run the program i load a.html, when the user scrolls to the top and if it is already the top the alert says "you have reached the top of the page and this is the first page".

Now when i scroll dowm, using the js way of detecting page end, when i reach page bottom i call the next page and load the next page that is b.html.

In this way when it reaches d.html and you scroll down to the end of the page its will alert you that "you have reached the page end and this is the last page".

Same method is used when i scroll up and when it reached the page top, js will call the previous page function and it will load the previous page.
in here i will load the previous page bottom first. this is also working fine(but there is no continuity)

This strategy is working fine. But i need a mechanism to load these html pages continuously so that it will load the webpages in a neat fashion as if i open a pdf doc in a doc viewer.

Like the next and previous page swaps are smooth rather that opening it as a new page(this is very important in the case of previous page calls).

Is there any library in jquery or java script for this functionality?

someone please help. I searched a lot for this functionality

Comment: I believe you're looking for 'infinite scrolling'. The 'smooth' transition you require will depend on a lot. How fast the server responds to requests, the connection, how eager you are to load subsequent pages (i.e. 2 pages in advance? 10 pages in advance?). If I were you, I would be loading these html pages with ajax. and appending them to a container beneath the other pages. I must say though, as an aside, it may be easier and equally as fast/faster (especially if they're only html) to just load them all initially and toggle visibility on scroll instead of async loading.

Comment: every html pages are loaded locally, same case like a pdf

Comment: Why do you load them in this way? Rather than all at once?

Comment: I would suggest using fullpage js https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page3 rather than creating different html pages and loading them , full page provides  fullscreen scrolling

Comment: my intention is to create a pdf sort of application with javascript

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ what if there are 100+ html pages ?

Comment: @Mukund if you have 100+ html page then no problem you can load html page one by one when user goes down.

Comment: okay but how can i dynamically load it as you guys are saying. Any code or library?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load HTML documents onto a webpage, you can use jQuery's `.load()` function.

**Syntax:**

```
// $ is the same as jQuery
$(element).load(documentURL);
```

Here, `.load()` gets the HTML from the document and puts this HTML into the element specified. To get specific elements in an HTML document, just locate them as you do in CSS. If you wanted to get the header from the document:

```
$("#result").load("myDocument.html header");
```

**Remember:** If you are loading the HTML on the DOM page load, use `$(document).ready();`. Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#result").load("myDoc.html body main");
});
```